# SharePoint 2010 Hardware Specification

Tags: .net, windows, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

As per the SharePoint 2010 requirements

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485(office.14).aspx

It require the below hardware specification

1. Processor : 64 bit 4 cores
2. Ram: 8 GB
3. Hard disk : 80 GB

I would like to know , Will the SharePoint 2010 will run in 2 core processor with 8 GB and 80 GB hard disk . If so  will it have any performance impact ?

Answer (score 0):

For installing the Sharepoint 2010 processor is not a problem. You must focus on Ram and Rom specification. But if you use this processor sharepoint will be slow otherwise we can install in 2 core processor.